# Catch windows.external.notify posted message from UIWebview in UIViewController Xamarin-iOS

Tags: xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I have a scenario where I'm trying to login from UIWebview and if authenticated successfully then I'm getting a string **token** using script snippet `window.external.notify` I'm able to get token in windows phone using `myWebView.ScriptNotify+=WinNotify;` and in android using `myWebView.AddJavascriptInterface(new ExternalInterface(),"");` 
but the problem is that I'm not able to detect any code snippet in iOS webview to read this notify script.

I've tried [This](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/) where I've used `IWKScriptMessageHandler` but didn't work.

Can you guys please help me to get it done in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this a some while ago for Azure Access Control Services. The code can be found here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins/blob/0e8b7765fe375d1d4998552074d664e6cf5397a3/AzureAccessControl/AzureAccessControl.Touch/Views/AccessControlWebAuthController.cs

Basically what this does is injecting a Notify script into the page, when that script is invoked, it navigates to a specific URL that I know and from that I can grab the payload.

```cs
private const string ScriptNotify = @"
    <script type=""text/javascript"">
        window.external = {
            'Notify': function(s) {
                document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; 
            }, 
            'notify': function(s) {
                document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; 
            }
        };
    </script>";
```

So the code above navigates to `acs://settoken?token=` when the notify script is invoked. You can detect this in `UIWebView.ShouldStartLoad` by checking the url scheme. If it matches the one in the notify script you are done.

To inject the script, I implement `NSUrlConnectionDelegate` and in the `FinishedLoading` override I inject it as part of the data and make the UIWebView load that content instead.

Comment: Master @Cheesebaron Thank you! I saw your code snippet and I have a doubt and that is an URL I'm using to load in webview already has this script `window.external.notify` while login success it notifying. Now, still need to inject your provided script?